# Weblogic Hibernate JPA error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, weblogic

I a facing  a crazy problem with hibernate in weblogic server 10.3.6, I am getting this  strange error: 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/spring-datasource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is  
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
```

I googled it and found that I have to configure weblogic to use the apis within the application, but no result. I also found that it may be a conflict in the versions, here is my **pom.xml** :

```
<properties>
<jackson.version>1.8.6</jackson.version>
<org.hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</org.hibernate.version>
<cxf.version>2.7.10</cxf.version>
<org.springframework.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- CXF Apache dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring dependencies -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I appreciate any suggestion, question and  remark.
Thanks for help and best regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it use `JPA 1.0` instead of `JPA 2.0`. `PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode` only exists in `JPA 2.0`. `JPA 1.0` is probably the default implementation for the version of `Weblogic` you are using. If you are not able to update the `JPA` version of `Weblogic`, you will need to use an older version of `hibernate-entitymanager` since the latest version that support `JPA 1.0` is `3.4` and you are currently using `3.6`.

Comment: I am using know the hibernate 4 version, but the problem is the same

Comment: I am using the hibernate-entitymanager 4.1.1.Final in pom.xml and the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence as persistence provider in persistence.xml

Comment: I am not using JPA 1.0, I am using JPA 2.0, If weblogic does I have to deactivate is as provide my jpa 2.0 with the application

Comment: That's what I said... You can either change the weblogic implementation OR use an use an older version of Hibernate. If you want to provide the JPA 2.0 implementation, you'll need to override the weblogic class chain loading.

Comment: I am trying with in know, hope I will progress in the right way, thanks for help, I will put the results here

Comment: hi I followed this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm  but the same problem persists